# String/Paragraph/Document comparison in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm trying to add a feature to generate a difference report between 2 20,000 character sections of text.  I've done some Googling and I heard about Pear's diff library - which has been discontinued - and found this: https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/5bfe1d2a8f967c7901ace50f04ac2d9308ed3169/simplediff.php

Ideally I'd like to see what was removed, edited, or added and be able to show that to the user.  Are there any libraries or simple ways of accomplishing this that you may know of?

Comment: Will this feature be used on a continual basis, or a one time thing? If one time usage, I would add the two files to version control and then diff the files against each other.

Comment: It'll be on demand for our customers, so it'll be all the time

Comment: Check CakePHP and Zend Framework, they may have something in their libs that deal with this type of situation. Another solution may be Lucene/Solr, but would take more time to ramp up.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in a live project
http://svn.geograph.org.uk/svn/branches/british-isles/libs/3rdparty/simplediff.inc.php

Example use
http://svn.geograph.org.uk/svn/branches/british-isles/public_html/article/diff.php

but the code is very simple

```
$a1 = explode("\n",$file1);
$a2 = explode("\n",$file2);
print diff2table($a1,$a2);
```

(the code just accepts the input as arrays, and outputs html table. But diff2table can be customised)

Comment: doh! see you already found simplediff. But maybe the usage I've shown helps. I've found it works find in real world use. It works on documents with 100k lines just fine.

Comment: I've found that it doesn't quite suit my needs.  It guesses sometimes, and I can't afford a guess.

Comment: Guesses? what an earth does that mean?

Comment: With that code, I ran a test appending new content to a string and the difference report wasn't accurate.  Local, yes, accurate, no.  I took the string "Insurance at low cost" and added "You can get" to the front of it.  It showed `<del>Insurance</del>` and `<ins>You can get Insurance</ins>`... it actually shouldn't show anything was removed.